# How to turn off bracket auto closing in Bluefish

Tags: linux, text-editor, bluefish

Does somebody know how to turn off bracket auto closing in bluefish?

Answer (score 2):

Open Bluefish and from Edit menu select Preferences. Dialog with title Edit Preferences shows up with Editor settings node selected in the tree, on the left hand side. On the right hand side is panel with properties. Under Options, the second group from the top, is check box with label Auto close brackets. Uncheck it and click on OK button.

Comment: How could I overlooked it... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Bluefish version 2.2.7 for Ubuntu it's in the same place as stated by Filip Bulovic, but a dropdown box: Never, Always, Smart.

In passing, for tags look here: Preferences -> Language support -> Generic HTML -> top box on the right:  Autocomplete tags.